# is the equipotent relation an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I know that the relation satisfy for $A,B,C$ sets, the following conditions.
$A$~$A$, if $A$~$B$ then $B$~$A$ and, if $A$~$B$ and $B$~$C$ then $A$~$C$.
but not necesary exist a set U such that $A,B,C \subset U$.

Can someone explains me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard facts first:

> The equipotency relation satisfies all the properties we require of equivalence relations, **except** that it actually doesn't exist as a set of pairs.

The exception doesn't really have anything to do with the concept of "*equivalence* relation" specifically. It's probably fair to say that if you recognize it as a "relation" at all, then you have no reason not to call it an "equivalence relation" too.

Whether you should *care* about not being a set depends on what your goal is.

The relations we meet in ordinary relations can pretty universally be represented as sets, so there the question of whether it's a set never really arises and we can go directly to checking the usual conditions. Only *within set theory itself* do we routinely encounter relations that are so large that it cannot be sets.*

In plenty of contexts this is not a problem, and it is much more useful to think of the relation that it satisfies the three usual conditions and therefore we can use the same intuition about it as we have already developed about equivalence relations in, say, abstract algebra. For the purpose of **guiding your intuition**, equipotency *should* without doubt be considered an equivalence relation.

But it should be kept in mind that the *formal* consequences of being an equivalence relation are not guaranteed here. For example, the equivalence classes are not sets.

*Actually not quite true. There are similar problems about things such as the "isomorphic to" relation between groups or other algebraic structures, which also is an equivalence relation but for not being a set.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to clarify the concept.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem is more philosophical than mathematical

- If you want to consider equivalence relations in a given model for set theory ([ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) is the standard one) then it doesn't make sense to define a relation between arbitrary sets;
- If you want to work with something that "look and feel like sets" but want to be able to talk about relations with sets, you should use "Classes" instead of "Sets". See for example [vNGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory). In this case we can talk about the *class* of all sets, which is not itself a set.
- If you want to avoid any of this and just work on a purely formal level, you can think you are doing [First order calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) on the usual [Formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) of mathematics, so you define a new binary symbol and prove that it satisfies the axioms for an equivalence relation [at a formal (symbolic) level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic).

The usual approach is... don't think too much about it. Of course you'd want to define a relation between sets - equipotency is really natural - so the first approach works only if you restrict yourself to sets which are all contained in a big "universe" set $U$. *But in this case you can't compare your big set $U$ with any of the sets if contains*. If you want to do that, you need to take the power set $P(U)$ of $U$, but you have the same problem again: *can't compare $P(U)$, in principle, with the other sets...

In general, you keep the second approach in mind (think of a "collection of all sets", whathever that is), but prove it formally, with the third approach, as you did.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think yes there does exist a set that contains $A, B, C$ and the set is $A\cup B \cup C$, and this is true for any arbitrary collection of sets.

Comment: but if that was true, implies that exist the set of all sets?

Comment: this is the same question that my professor asked me yesterday and he said that if such set exists then it contains itself!! I am very much confused with that fact. I think that I need to collect some proofs to answer your last question.